# Repairing Hardwood Floor, Two Different Joint Systems

Tags: hardwood-floor, engineered-flooring

My master bedroom closet took some water damage. The closet and bedroom have the same engineered wood flooring. I am trying to replace the engineered floor in the closet only. However, the closest matching flooring replacement planks I could find don't have the same joint-locking system as my current flooring.

Does anyone know of any techniques to make this project work? I am replacing ALL of the floor in the closest, so technically the only place that the two different joints will meet is in the doorway to the closet, where the old flooring will meet the new. Tongue and groove meets locking joints, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are "tee" moldings, or transition moldings, that the flooring people make that goes with the new laminate that you are planning to use.

Answer (score 1):

Make an "adapter" by removing the interlocking piece from an old and a new segment, joining them together with compatible glue on the edge, and reinforcing the bottom with a thin material (perhaps heavy fabric)  glued along the joined edges. This depends, of course, on being able to remove and modify some of the existing flooring without damage.